# R - Daily to Montly Time Series - Repeated Days

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with daily time series which I want to convert to monthly, in the following format:

```
DATE    VALOR
3/5/2014    8.9
3/5/2014    50
3/5/2014    50
3/6/2014    77.4
3/7/2014    97.95
3/8/2014    118.5
3/8/2014    139.05
3/8/2014    159.6 
3/10/2014   180.15    
3/11/2014   200.7
```

As can be seen, the days are not homogeneously repeated in the database. What is the best way to proceed? Besides that, the column VALOR should be a SUM, not a MEAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the time-series in your `data.frame` should be aggregated by `sum()` then one could try:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = format(DATE, "%Y-%m")]
```

A small example:

```
df <- data.frame(DATE = seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), length.out = 100, by = 1)
                 , x1 = 1:100, x2 = 1:100)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(Date = format(DATE, "%Y-%m"))]
      Date   x1   x2
1: 2016-01  496  496
2: 2016-02 1334 1334
3: 2016-03 2356 2356
4: 2016-04  864  864
```

Answer (score 1):

Read it in using zoo creating the zoo object shown. The index will be a yearmon object which directly represents year/month.

Note that unlike using character strings to represent year/month this gives a year/month that can be manipulated (e.g. add one month to it, use it with plot and ggplot, etc.)

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(df, FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%m/%d/%Y", aggregate = sum)
```

giving:

```
> z 
Mar 2014 
 1082.25
```

If you need a data frame result use `fortify.zoo(z)`.

**Note:**  Input in reproducible form assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "
DATE    VALOR
3/5/2014    8.9
3/5/2014    50
3/5/2014    50
3/6/2014    77.4
3/7/2014    97.95
3/8/2014    118.5
3/8/2014    139.05
3/8/2014    159.6 
3/10/2014   180.15    
3/11/2014   200.7"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm understanding it correct you want to group by month (and assuming by year as well). Using dplyr

```
df %>%
mutate(month = format(date, "%m"), year = format(date, "%Y")) %>%
group_by(month, year) %>%
summarise(total_sum = sum(value))
```